# Firebase Kotlin Reference more than one child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database for my Android application using Kotlin.

I have my JSON in the below format.

```
    {
  "main1": {
    "branch1": [
      {
        "a": "Test1",
        "b": "Test2"
      },
      {
        "a": "Test3",
        "b": "Test4"
      }
    ],
    "branch2": [
      {
        "a": "Test5",
        "b": "Test6"
      },
      {
        "a": "Test7",
        "b": "Test8"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to get results for more than one child and get them displayed in the Recycler view.

Currently I'm able to populate only from one child with the below code.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("main1").child("branch1")
```

But I'm not able to find a query to get combined results for both branch1 and branch2. Also I could have main2 with branch3 and branch4.

How can I get them as single output for multiple child to be displayed on the RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way in which you can perform a query and get all those objects in a single go. However, there is a workaround in which you can make some changes in your database structure, by reducing the number of children. So please check the below schema:

```
{
  "main1": {
      {
        "a": "Test1",
        "b": "Test2",
        "branch1": true
      },
      {
        "a": "Test3",
        "b": "Test4"
        "branch1": true
      },
      {
        "a": "Test5",
        "b": "Test6"
        "branch2": true
      },
      {
        "a": "Test7",
        "b": "Test8"
        "branch2": true
      }
  }
}
```

If you want to get all objects, simply use the following reference:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("main1");
```

If you want to get all object of type `branch1`, use the following query:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("main1")
    .orderByChild("branch1")
    .equalTo(true);
```